# Progressbar in DataTable?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, progress-bar

I am planning to program a downloader in C#.

I want to put the filename, size etc. in a DataTable (see *all* torrent clients). The Table should also contain a progressbar (again, like in a torrent client).

But when I call

```
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Progress", typeof(ProgressBar)));
```

It only shows the properties of the bar as string.

Is there any way I can change that?

I am using WPF, in case this is important.

Thank you!

Comment: What are you binding the data to?

Comment: @Servy I am not sure if you mean that, but I call 

     `dataGrid.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView`

So a DataGrid